# SEEK for Android from Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, javacard, sim-card, open-mobile-api

I would like to create an Android app using C# from Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin extension. This application should communicate with a Java Card applet loaded on SIM card using SEEK for Android library.

According to the SEEK documentation, I should replace the SDK used for compilation. I can do this easily in Eclipse or Android Development Studio:

[image]

However, I don't know how to achieve this in Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

Open Mobile API doesn't appear in the list box "Compile using Android version", although I installed it successfully in the SDK manager. Are there any secret settings in VS 2015 I missed?

Comment: Try changing `Target Framework`. If i remember correctly it's located in `Build` tab

Comment: @misho it is usually in the Application tab, but it is not there for an Android app... I didn't find it in other tabs either...

Comment: Not sure about the SDK option, but you could definitely create a [bindings library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/) for the Open Mobile API JAR (make sure to use the InputJar build action though).

Comment: @MichaelRoland Could you please post a link to Open Mobile API jar? All tutorials and links I have found use a special SDK, no extra jars. Where did you find it?

Comment: There is no ready-made one, but you can compile one from [the library project in the smartcard service GitHub repo](https://github.com/seek-for-android/platform_packages_apps_SmartCardService/tree/android-5.0.0_r3-scapi/openmobileapi).